# "Unrecognized option: --format=COBERTURAXML" in trying to convert JSCover report to cobertura xml

Tags: cobertura, jscoverage

I'm trying to convert JSCover to cobertura xml.

Based on what i've read the command is as follows:

```
java -cp JSCover-all.jar jscover.report.Main --format=COBERTURAXML REPORT-DIR SRC-DIRECTORY
```

But I get an error

> "Error: Could not find or load main class jscover.report.Main"

Even if I set the fully qualified path of there the **JSCover-all.jar** is located.

So I tried including the **JSCover-al.jar** into the classpath and run the following command instead:

```
java -cp jscover.report.Main --format=COBERTURAXML target/local-storage-proxy target/local-storage-proxy/original-src
```

I no longer get the first error but i'm now getting the following error:

> Unrecognized option: --format=COBERTURAXML
>
> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

I hope someone could help me with it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The first attempt is the correct approach. The error means that JSCover-all.jar is not in the same directory that you are executing the command from. An absolute path to is not needed - a relative one will do.

In the second approach, you have passed 'jscover.report.Main' as the class-path to the JVM and '--format=COBERTURAXML' as parameter to the 'java' command.